# Writing/Reading an object(socket in java)

Tags: java, sockets, object

My question is that I have an object class( packet) which contains another object (msg) in it. I make **both classes implements Serializable**. But when I run my program I see this error "java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 00" some part of my code :

```
outStrm=new ObjectOutputStream(mySocket.getOutputStream());
inStrm=new ObjectInputStream(mySocket.getInputStream());
outStrm.writeObject(new packet());
outStrm.flush();
```

and on the server side I read like this

```
Socket client = listen_socket.accept();
in=new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
out=new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
p=(packet) in.readObject();
```

I send many packets and the weird part is that when I debug it(step by step) I wont see the error but when I run it I have this error! Please help me.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

class ServerThre
    extends Thread
{
    Socket client;
    ObjectInputStream in;
    ObjectOutputStream out;

    public ServerThre(Socket client_socket)
    {
        client = client_socket;
        try
        {
            in = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            try
            {
                client.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e2)
            {
            }
            System.err.println("Exception while getting input streams: " + e);
            return;
        }
        this.start();
    }

    private packet getPacket() throws IOException
    {
        packet p;
        try
        {
            p = (packet)in.readObject();
            if (p != null)
            {
                return p;
            }
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while (!client.isClosed())
        {

            packet p = null;
            try
            {
                p = getPacket();
            }
            catch (IOException e1)
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (p == null)
            {
                System.out.print("Connection closed by server, exiting");
                return;
            }

        }// end of while
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to post your code and the stack trace. The problem is in code you *aren't* showing, not in the 8 lines you posted.

Comment: Is it true that I made both of my classes implements serializable?My total code is a lot.

Comment: Lets try this - read this: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Create one that demonstrates the problem you are having. Come back, post that. No one can help you as it is. There's nothing wrong with the snippit you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several oddities in this code.

1. The test for `p != null` in `getPacket()` is completely pointless.
2. The later test that equates `p == null` with the connection being closed is incorrect. You would get an EOFException under that circumstance, not a null.
3. Socket.isClosed() only tells you whether *you* have closed the socket.

'Invalid type code' usually arises when you use a single ObjectInputStream for reading and multiple ObjectOutputStreams for writing, or the other way around. Use one of each for the life of the socket at both ends.